# Argument of (5,-5) in polar co-ordinate

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert $\ [5,-5]   $ into polar form.I determined the argument of this co-ordinate.
it is $\ \theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{-5}{5}= \frac{-\pi}{4}$.
As the co-ordinate is fourth-quadrant.So,its range should be $\ \frac{3\pi}{2} \lt \theta \lt 2\pi $ So,I modify it like this,

argument z $ \ = 2\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{7\pi}{4} $.But the answer is $\ \frac{-\pi}{4} $

I don't know what i have done wrong.

Comment: it's basicaly the same

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ is many-valued. The possible values of $\tan^{-1}(-1)$ are $-\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$ for integral $k$. One of your values uses $k=0$, the other uses $k=2$.

Comment: You have done nothing wrong. Check to see if there were additional instructions which specified a particular range for the answer, or whether you were advised to use a specific formula for finding the argument.

Comment: @SakethMalyala:  You need a range of $2\pi$ for the answer, not a range of $\pi$.  What is the angle of $(-3,3)?$

Comment: OOPS sorry i wasn't paying attention @RossMillikan

Answer (score 0):

It is just a question of which representation is desired.  $\frac {-\pi}4$ and $\frac {7\pi}4$ represent the same direction.  Presumably whoever made the answer key expects arguments to be in the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi)$and you are expecting arguments to be in the range $[0,2\pi)$.  They both work.

Comment: so.that means my answer is correct?